# Why maker of symfony will abort command line actions that require user input on a docker project on windows?

Tags: symfony, command, php-8, symfony6, php-8.1

I am developing a project with Symfony 6.1 on Windows 11 PC. The project is in a docker container.

The problem happens on any execution which requires user input such as: php bin/console make:entity
Therefore, I can't even modify a class or choose my preferences.

Other commands like php bin/console make:migration which don't need user input work fine so it seems like the wait for input is the problem.

My database is recognized and I can create a User using the command : php bin/console make:user but the process can't finish since input doesn't work.

Here is the output from the terminal:

docker exec -w /var/www/project www_project php bin/console make:entity

Class name of the entity to create or update (e.g. GrumpyPuppy):

> 

Aborted.

make:entity [-a|--api-resource] [-b|--broadcast] [--regenerate] [--overwrite] [--] []

I tried it with PHP 8.2, it doesn't work either. It doesn't seem to be linked to the version of PHP.

Does somebody know where the problem is coming from ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the maker-bundle of Symfony couldn't work completely when used from the docker container. I had to download PHP 8.1 on my machine and modify the environment variable PATH to add it.
Then, instead of :
docker exec -w /var/www/project www_project php bin/console make:entity
I went inside the symfony project and made the usal command :
php bin/console make:entity

Now the terminal accepts user input.